# Why is there a current in my house panel grounding strip

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, utilities

When I measure current in the grounding strip coming from my house electric panel to the water pipe using clamp meter I am getting slowly fluctuating value from 1.5 A all the way to 4 A. In my understanding (I have PhD in physics and I work as an electronics engineer, so it is a reasonably good understanding) this strip is normally not supposed to carry any significant current.

Now, this current is not a result of any problem inside the house. The ground and neutral wires are bonded together inside the panel (I've checked), so even if something in the house leaks current to the ground wire this current returns to the neutral in the panel, it does not go into the grounding strip.

I am reasonably sure that utility neutral is bonded to earth at street transformer as well, so ground strip and water pipe and earth is just another way for current to return to the transformer, parallel to the neutral utility wire. But utility wire is 1 inch thick metal conductor and creates a very easy path for current to return, there should not be any reason for 4A of current to go through the grounding strip unless there is something wrong with utility neutral.

Is there any other explanation? I started measuring things because my power consumption is abnormal and I am looking for a reason.

Best regards,
Alex.

Comment: On the way to a possible explanation; Do you have an electrically powered water Heater?

Comment: Do you have grounding rods? I take it your power consumption is abnormally *high*, right?

Comment: High resistance connection on a neutral lug in the main panel, meter, or on the pole is a possibility.  It happens. It will also worsen over time because the by-product is heat that overtime arcs, burns, expands/contracts etc.   Call your power company for a meter and pole connection check.

Comment: Clamp meter all 4 wires at the edge of the panel.  L1 minus L2 should equal N.  Also turn off one breaker at a time (or turn off half and do a binary tree search) and see if it stops with a single breaker turn off.  If it defies being narrowed down to one or a few breakers, that means something else.

Comment: Answer on comments:

Comment: Answering on comments: no, there is no electric water heater. No ground rods either, strip is clamped to the house water main. If I clamp the whole utility cable coming to the panel it reads the same as grounding strip - no surprises here. The panel is 4-years old, still shiny, no signs of corrosion, every clamp is tight, but maybe there is a problem upstream. I will try power company, but i am not holding my breath :-). Thanks for comments!

Comment: What @Harper is reminding you above is 120/240 volt split phase service the service neutral only carries the imbalance of L1 and L2.  Consider this: Imagine that we have a brand new live panel (no circuits installed yet).  Now add 2 circuits one each to L1 and L2.  Lets have each circuit supply ten 100w incandescent lights, 1000w total per circuit. Turn all on.  L1 wil read 8.33 amps, L2 will also read 8.33 amps and N and G should both read ZERO.   If you have a current going to ground via the water pipe bond then you have a bad Neutral connection where it enters the panel or upstream.

Comment: I meant clqmp them one at a time, but whatevs - you've found it.   If you clamp the entire utlity cable, it should read ZERO.   Current on all three conductors should cancel each other out.   With main breaker off does the current persist in these locations?  Is the neutral-ground bond in your main panel present and intact?

Comment: Well, I've found nothing new by clamping utility cable - the current that leaks through the grounding strip does not return through the neutral, creating equal imbalance in the utility cable. I do not expect L1 and L2 to be anywhere near balance in the house, and my clamp meter does not fit to measure neutral only. The neutral and ground are the same bus in the main panel. There are 8 people living in the house, so I am trying to investigate all theoretical possibilities before starting to throw breakers :-).

Comment: I had a thought for a sec about disconnecting grounding strip and measuring voltage in the gap, but the notion of turning everything in the house hot if I really have problem with neutral kinda stopped me :-(.

Comment: All current returns to its SOURCE via the shortest path.  That’s about as theoretical as it can get. The most direct route is supposed be the service neutral.  If service neutral has a bad high resistance connection along the way, then that current has to find another path, yours is using the water pipe bond.  Do NOT disconnect the water pipe bond in attempt to measure voltage, that will likely fry everything in the house.  Call the utility!

Comment: The purpose of my example above was to show that neutral only carries the imbalanced load, not the combined load.  The water pipe bond should alway carry zero.  If water pipe bonding conductor is carrying something then it’s because that load couldn’t get on the fast way back to the source, and it’s finding another path.

Comment: Ouch, you're going to need to set a time-of-day at mutual convenience that power will be going down. And I would make it repeating.  That's the sincerest type of neutral-ground bond there is.  Shame about the neutral being unclampable.  You can eliminate a branch circuit if it passes three tests: you clamp all wires with ground and it is equal/zero, and you clamp all conductors and not ground and it sitll reads equal/zero, and you clamp the ground strap and it's still leaking,

Comment: Is the amperage higher on rainy days than dry ones?  Check the voltage in any random receptacle,  is it very near 120V?  If not, check another receptacle on the opposite pole, are they unequal but add up to ~240V? Here I'm fishing for a different thing, a lost neutral problem.

Comment: Voltages are 125V, 125V and 250V, everything is symmetrical. I've bought a bunch of SCT013 non-invasive current sensors, I am going to hang them on every circuit in the panel and throw together a multi-input recording monitor, so over a week I can figure out where the power drain is. The house does have about 14 desktops (that sleep most of the time) and 2 24/7 NAS servers, plus usual house stuff, but 2000 kWh a month, very uniform, any season, still strikes me as a bit too much. My first effort to involve utility company ended up in vague promise to send a technician eventually.

Comment: A tech house.  Yes I see the problem in getting that powered down.  Well, you can't just go "it's inconvenient not gonna", this is not a $1/day problem, this is a burn your house down problem that hasn't happened yet, it's like all the aircrashes where 4 problems converge to create a perfect storm, you just happen to be one element shy of the perfect storm.    Also, since when did techies stop caring about power quality?   This power is not safe to plug your PC into!

Comment: I'm not at all confident this is a branch circuit problem, if the goal is to pursue this problem, you are throwing good money after bad unless you have other reasons to want those sensors.  In any case, using them in the conventional way (on hots) will be absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question and reading your background I am betting you may have a lot of electronics in your house and you actually have two problems. First you are picking current in a ground and second you seem to have an unusual power consumption. When you put them together as single problem it generally boils down to Harmonic Distortion, K-factor. Electronics, as an example a UPS, have a habit of recreating the wave and causing a distortion due to the time lap in the return current in the neutral. Also Electronics have a habit of using the ground as a handshake between components causing a current flow in a ground.

> K-factor is a weighting of the harmonic load currents according to their effects on transformer heating, as derived from ANSI/IEEE C57.110. A K-factor of 1.0 indicates a linear load (no harmonics). The higher the K-factor, the greater the harmonic heating effects.

I am not sure but by reading your question I think the water pipe your are clamping to is not bonded back to the single point of reference at your ground. If that's correct you really need to do that. Also instead of trying to troubleshoot the panel try and turn off any electronics in you residence and see if that helps correct your problem.

As far as knowing whether or not this is the real problem with your power consumption. You would really have to run a power analysis to know for sure. FYI this type of equipment runs in the neighborhood of about $5,000.00. So I would suggest you find someone who does this for a living and try and work out some sort of quote if you feel it is necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean like in Wreck-It Ralph, with the toons running up and down the electrcial wires?  That would not account for three amps on the ground *leaving the house*.  Even if he has a fairly serious ground fault, it should return to neutral via the neutral-ground bond in the main panel, not to the water pipe to lots of dirt to the ground wire at the transformer.

Comment: @Harper exactly  notice my comment "I think the water pipe you are clamping to is not bonded back to the single point of reference at your ground". The only way you are picking up a different potential in the ground would be if that particular point you are measuring is not connected to the neutral-ground bond. If you remember in the 1980's everyone was having a problem requiring a separate and isolated ground in computer rooms and they began having the same problem  user3781341 is describing. To fix it we had to run their ground back to the original ground to establish a 0 reference.

Comment: @Harper - The other problem I see is that with amperage there must be voltage but what is the voltage. So there is current between the two reference points. My best guess is that it would be a harmonic, but I am just guessing. We can't establish the true problem without some sophisticated equipment thus the power analyser. Every other cure is just hit or miss.

Comment: Well my concern is: the current is returning through *dirt*.  Dirt is not a great conductor. The only voltage that *should* be present in the house  is 120V, **which he pays for**, so try this on for size: what if the voltage is 120V? If so resistance is E=IR  120=1.5xR on the low side, 120=4R on the high side, R is 30-80 ohms. That's exactly what we'd expect for dirt.  My theory is the leakage is normal 120 and it's possible his house is floating 120 above neighborhood earth.

Comment: That's a scary notion, @Harper :-). I did clamp SCT013 non-invasive current sensor onto the grounding strip and connected oscilloscope to it. It looks much more like triangular wave than sinusoidal, but it is still 60Hz. My water main is 1-inch copper pipe, I wonder if it somehow gets to the street transformer directly, in this case it provides almost as good current path as neutral.

Comment: @gmygmy everything about this deal is scary!  Never mind the $1/day, it also means if you lift that grounding strap, you'll get a heck of a whomp and there'll be 120V between your panel ground and your grounding electrode!  That shouldn't be!  Grounds shouldn't bite!  I would say your water pipe is in danger of being eaten by galvanic corrosion.  Dirt is a terrible conductor and can't substitute for neutral... if it was, this problem would be *resolving itself*  much more spectacularly...